# How to calculate DB SPL given DB FS

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm working on creating a volume fader using web audio api that allows for a gain of +12db. So far I've calculated the `dbFS` value for the peak meter.

How do I derive a `dbSPL` value given the `dbFS`? From what I understand, volume faders in daw use `dbSPL` while peak meters use `dbFS`. Somehow a conversion must be taking place. How do I implement the conversion ?

what I have so far:

```
//create random amplitude values ranging 0 to 1
let amplitudes = Array.from({ length: 16 }, (_,i) => Math.random() * 1);

//calculate average amplitude
let average = amplitudes.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / 16;

// derive dbFS of given average amplitude value
let dbFS = 20 * Math.log10(average)

//update input element value
peakMeter.value = dbFS;
```

Now I would like to do the same for volume fader

```
let dbSPL = //?????

fader.value = spl

//Translate dbSPL back to dbFS then update gain value
audioNode.gain.value = // ???
```

Any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: There is no calculable connection, since it is a completely different size.
`dbfs` can not be reduced to physical quantities (unlike `dbspl`, `dbu`, `dbv` etc.).

`db` is a logarithmic unit of measurement for ratios of any sizes. `fs` stands for full-scale.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by code **exactly**? Is it **(a)** to increase levels of bass / mid / treble frequencies, or **(b)** just to create some type of master gain (increasing amplitude values)? Remember you'll have the audio data as PCM values (amplitude range **-1.0** to max **+1.0**) in front of you (in a byte array), so decide which effect you want from the gain slider (volume fader).